# Center view in viewed screen

Tags: android, xml, view, scrollview

I was searching across all the web, but I didn't see anyone asking this:
Hi have a `scroolview` and I need a `view` to be centered in the viewed screen, I mean:
I setted a `gravity:center` `attribute`, but when the `scrollview` gets longer that `view` isn't visible anymore because centered in the `scrollview` and not in the screen of the phone. How can I make the `view` centered in the size of screen that you're seeing?

## EDIT, XML

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFEFD5"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_layout"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <EditText
                app:layout_widthPercent="75%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="12%"
                android:id="@+id/testo"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="9%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="9%"
                android:background="#F5F5F5"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
                android:hint="Please, insert the text for the new button."
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLength="19"/>


            <Button
                app:layout_widthPercent="75%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="12%"
                android:layout_below="@id/testo"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="9%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="9%"
                app:layout_marginBottomPercent="3%"
                android:text="Accept"
                android:id="@+id/accept"/>

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: why do you use a scrollview?

Comment: Show us the relevant xml, otherwise noone can help you.

Comment: @XaverKapeller edited; masoudvali just because I need it :)

Comment: Many things are wrong in that xml. Which view do you want to center?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Why are many things wrong? It works to me; I want to center all the `PercentRelativeLayout`

Comment: @DISSENNATORE For example: Why does the `FrameLayout` In your `ScrollView` have `match_parent` as height? That can't work and makes me think you don't understand how layouting in Android works. Why is the view you want to center a child of the `FrameLayout` in your `ScrollView`? Of course than the view can never be centered on the screen. If it looks like its working on your end then only because you don't notice all the things that are not working.

Comment: Why are there namespace declarations randomly somewhere in the middle of your xml? They are supposed to be at the very top. Why do you have a `PercentRelativeLayout` with `wrap_content` and then percentage based width and height on the children? That's also wrong. Works only because the `PercentRelativeLayout` is programmed to gracefully fail when somebody does this.

Comment: @XaverKapellerCan you give me an example for the namespace declaration that you're talking about? And for `wrap_content ` attributes: yes, you're right, I've already known that: simply those parameters were generated automatically, so I set them to `wrap_content` to make quickier the xml and to see the rendering in the visualizer, but then I simply forgot to delete them :) Thanks for the warn :)

Comment: @DISSENNATORE I am talking about this: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` which you for some reason have on your `PercentRelativeLayout`. They aren't supposed to be there. Android Studio should warn you about it. If you were using data binding this would cause compile errors - at least when performing a release build.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Oh, thanks :) For the main problem what do you think I should do?

Comment: @DISSENNATORE I already told you. Fix all these issues and then it will work. 1) Fix the widths and heights, replace the `PercentRelativeLayout` with something more appropriate. 2) Move the view you want to center up a few levels. It can't work as long as it is a child of the `ScrollView`. For example put the `ScrollView` inside a `FrameLayout` and then add the `View` you want to center to that `FrameLayout` with `android:layout_gravity="center"`. 3) Get rid of the superflous namespace declarations.

Comment: You probably also don't need the `fillViewport="true"`.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



        </FrameLayout>

    </ScrollView>
     <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#FFEFD5"
                android:id="@+id/dialog_layout"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <EditText
                    app:layout_widthPercent="75%"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="12%"
                    android:id="@+id/testo"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="9%"
                    app:layout_marginRightPercent="9%"
                    android:background="#F5F5F5"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
                    android:hint="Please, insert the text for the new button."
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLength="19"/>


                <Button
                    app:layout_widthPercent="75%"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="12%"
                    android:layout_below="@id/testo"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="9%"
                    app:layout_marginRightPercent="9%"
                    app:layout_marginBottomPercent="3%"
                    android:text="Accept"
                    android:id="@+id/accept"/>

            </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why did you insert `centerInParent` attribute in the `scrollview`? I need to center only the `PercentRelativeLayout`

Comment: Android studio warn me: "Invalid layout param in a FrameLayout"

Comment: Dude is that running?

Comment: There are a couple things wrong with this answer, don't use it. See the things I said in the comments on the question.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I've tried his suggestion with your changes (not already with deleting the `fillViewPort`); it works, but not properly, I mean: now the `PercentRelativeLayout` is visible because the `scrollview` is automatically scrolled to his vertical half, but that `PercentRelativeLayout` still remains in the center of the `scrollview` instead of the center of the screen.. And Halumz, don't be rude, it isn't necessary

Comment: @DISSENNATORE That's impossible if you did it correctly. You must be doing something wrong, but I can't tell you what unless you show me. And you shouldn't use a `PercentRelativeLayout` here. As I already said this can't work properly..

Comment: @XaverKapeller now that the scrollview got longer than the last test I still have the same problem that I had without `centerInParent`; and yes, it is possible: the documentation says that the `view` is centered in his containers, which in this case is the scrollview

Comment: @DISSENNATORE You didn't understand what I was talking about... And you don't seem to understand how a `ScrollView` works... Try this: https://gist.github.com/Wrdlbrnft/49f813bca0db3a687c4896f20bc559d9 If you just use the xml from the gist then I guarantee you that it will work.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I saw it and I do not see anything (important) different.. If you want I'll edit my post with the whole xml